# Hackerrank Week Of Code 33 Pattern Count

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have been trying this question on Hackerrank.
I have tried using regex in python. But it fails in the test case "1001010001".
Can anybody please help? It gives output as 2 but expected output is 3.
(as in 1001 101 10001) . How does python actually handle this(in terms of an algorithm?)

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w33/challenges/pattern-count

```
import re
text=(raw_input().strip('\n'))
patregex=re.compile(r'1(0)*1')
p=patregex.findall(text)
print(len(p))
```

Comment: `404` when you click on the link...

Comment: Please include the essential parts of your question in the question body.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w33/challenges  . Second challenge in this.

Comment: A regex does **not** match overlapping parts (by default).

Comment: Thank You. Is there a way around this problem in regex? To solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression does **not count overlapping matches**.

You can however easily modify the code, to:

```
import re

patregex=re.compile(r'10*1')

text= raw_input().strip('\n')

cnt = 0
pos = 0
match = patregex.search(text)
while match:
    match = patregex(text,match.end()-1)
    cnt += 1
print(cnt)
```

So here when we find a `match`, we will try to find another match starting and the `match.end()-1` of the previous match, until no other match can be found. We do this until no match can be found anymore. For each match we increment the `cnt += 1`.

We can use `match.end()-1` because every match starts with a 1 followed by zero or more 0s and another 1. So we know that the pattern can only *restart* at the last match.

The approach will also save on memory: since after you find a first match, you can simply forget about that match when looking for the next one. A `findall(..)` approach, needs to store all matches in memory at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by a regular expression and a look ahead pattern to catch the case of an overlapping `1`:

```
import re

def count_code33(input_string):
    return len(re.findall('10*(?=1)', input_string))

# Test section    
def test(input_string):
    print('{!r} => {}'.format(input_string, count_code33(input_string)))

test('')
test('0')
test('10')
test('1001010001')
test('1001 101 10001')
test('100110110001')
test('1111')
```

Result:

```
'' => 0
'0' => 0
'10' => 0
'1001010001' => 3
'1001 101 10001' => 3
'100110110001' => 5
'1111' => 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help:)